# C# WebSocketClient always receives garbage data

Tags: c#, websocket

I am connecting to a websocket server in C# using WebSocketClient class. I can connect to it successfully as the socket state changes to Open. When I try to receive data from the socket I get garbage data always.
the garbage data looks like following

> \u0002\u0004\0\u0003Y\\0\04D\0\0\0\0^��$\0\0\0\0����

The client side code works fine if I connect to other server. Server is a third party.

```
var buffer = new ArraySegment<byte>(new byte[8192]);
            using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
            {
                WebSocketReceiveResult result;
                do
                {
                    ct.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();

                    result = await socket.ReceiveAsync(buffer, ct);
                    ms.Write(buffer.Array), buffer.Offset, result.Count);
                }
                while (!result.EndOfMessage);

                ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                if (result.MessageType == WebSocketMessageType.Binary)
                {
                    using (var reader = new StreamReader(ms, Encoding.UTF8))
                    {
                        //garbage data in str 
                        var str = await reader.ReadToEndAsync();
                        return feed;
                    }
                }
```

Any idea why this happens?

Third party server is http://antplus.aliceblueonline.com/#feeds-api

Comment: We cant help you since you havent specified which server you use. You only said that the Server is a "Third Party" server. Provide more information which could help us figuring the problem out. The only that could be possible is that the server sends encrypted data. If not you have to give us information about the server.

Comment: Added information about the third party server at the end of question.

Comment: Have you checked the encoding , and are sure that its `UTF8`? It might not be garbage , just wrong encoding.